# Search through products of store based on stores location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, searchkick

I have two models, Product and Store which are associated together via Stock model.

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  searchkick
  has_many :stocks
  has_many :stores, through: :stocks
end
```

#

```
class Store < ApplicationRecord
  searchkick locations: [:location]
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :stocks
  has_many :products, through: :stocks
end
```

Using Searchkick (Elastic) or ActiveRecord I want to search the products and get the products matching the query including the stores which have them, ordered by distance of those stores (the order part is not very important).

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way using ActiveRecord is to fetch all Products matching search and in next query retrieve Stores that have those products like this:

```
products = Product.where(your_search_params)
stores = Stores.joins(:stocks).where('stocks.product_id IN (?)', products.ids)
```